# problem when read files from local computer in pyscript

Tags: file, browser, pyscript

When I run the Python file, the file works correctly, but when I run the Python file with the script, it gives an error in read txt file(file not found).

[image]

how can i solve this problem؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue report](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/338).

Code running in a webpage is sandboxed and can't freely access files on the computer hosting the browser.

(It would be a terrible security problem if just visiting a webpage would give the author of the page access to your files).

If you want to access a file on the user's computer, use `<input type="file">` and have the user select it. I don't know if you can access it directly or if you would need to use a JavaScript `FileReader` and then pass the results from JS to PyScript … but one of those two approaches should be possible.

Comment: Sorry, we answered at the same time. Yes, you can use the FileReader in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Software written in any language (Python, JavaScript, WASM) cannot access local files directly. This is a browser security restriction. The browser can access files on behalf of your application using the `<input type="file">` DOM element [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

In Python and JavaScript, you must provide the user with a file input selector. The user selects the file and your application can the retrieve the file data from the browser.

In JavaScript this functionality is implemented with the `FileReader` class. This class can be used in Python via the `create_proxy()` function to proxy event callbacks.

If you are just getting started with Pyscript, I have written a number of articles [link](https://www.jhanley.com/category/pyscript/).